# jquery - Display div only after async calls are complete

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

On my page, there are two `Divs` *A & B*.

`Div B` is hidden by default.

`Div A` contains only a `button`. Upon its click I want *A* to hide & *B* to be displayed.

But the contents of div *B* contains some data which is getting flooded by async REST calls.

So I want *B* to be only displayed when all of its contents are ready.

**HTML:**

```
<div id="A">
    <button id="button1">Click here</button>
</div>
<div id="B"></div>
```

**JS Code**

```
//Approach 1 I tried:
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#B").hide();  // Div B hidden by default
    $("#button1").click(function () {
        $.when (
            renderChildPage()
        ).done (
            $("#B").show()
        )
    });
});

function renderChildPage() {
    // 1. some async calls
    // 2. fill some elements in Div B.
}
```

But above code is not working as some elements in Div *B* gets displayed, while some are not.

```
//Approach 2 I tried:
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#B").hide(); // Div B hidden by default
    $("#button1").click(function (){
        $("#B").show();
        renderChildPage;        // Code even working without it.
    });
});


var renderChildPage = (function () {
    // 1. some async calls
    // 2. fill some elements in Div B.
})();
```

This approach works but even if I do not call `renderChildPage()`, that function is still getting called and displaying the contents in div *B*.

Can some please suggest what should be the correct approach?

Also in approach 2 why the code is getting executed, without call.

*Thank You*

Comment: Assuming `renderChildPage()` return Promise, Use callback function i.e.  `$.when (
            renderChildPage()
        ).done (function(){
            $("#B").show()
        })`

Comment: Use windows bind to run after the page has been loaded. 
     $(window).bind("load", function() {
     // code here
     });

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your approach is correct. `done` takes a callback and executes when `when` is completed.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#B").hide();  // Div B hidden by default
    $("#button1").click(function () {
        $.when (
            renderChildPage();
        ).done (function(){
            $("#B").show()
          }
        )
    });
});
```

Comment: But even if I don't call `renderChildPage()` inside when, the method still gets called onClick. How?

Comment: you need to include a callback `function(){}` inside done.

Comment: Fixed!! Also needed to change how renderChildPage is defined. Solution - https://jsfiddle.net/1wyqc4tu/. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Do this:

```
).done(function() {
    $("#B").show();
});
```

Instead of this:

```
).done (
    $("#B").show()
)
```

Or just add `$("#B").show();` inside `renderChildPage()` function after you fill the content.